# User objects has no attribute profile

Tags: django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

Can anybody explain me why am in getting this error.

I have two models *User* and *Profile* with OnetoOne relations.
**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, verbose_name='phone number')
    email = models.EmailField()

class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

and here's the **serializer.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields =["first_name", "last_name"]

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "phone_number", "email", "profile",]
```

**Views.py**

```
class UserDetailsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the serializer in wrong way. The profile model has user column & user table doesn't have profile column and one thing Use OneToOne filed when creating a profile model against a user. Because one profile can contain one user.

```
models.py

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, verbose_name='phone 
    number')
    email = models.EmailField()


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)


serializers.py

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "phone_number", "email"]

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields =["first_name", "last_name", "user"]
```

for more information about nested serializer please follow the [official documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: @Orynnn you're welcom. Keep exploring.